# clearTimeout not working because function isnt defined

Tags: javascript, timeout

Before you tell me that javascript reads code from top to bottom, let me just say that I know that. So I have a page with a function called `startBallEasy()` and another function under it called `stopLoop()`. This is basically what it is:

```
var foo = 1;
var loop;

function startBallEasy() {
    if(foo==1) {
        alert("foo is 1!");
    } else {
        stopLoop();
    }

    loop = setTimeout("startBallEasy()",10);
}

function stopLoop() {
    clearTimeout(loop);
}
```

so `startBallEasy()` pretty much loops itself. If it is a certain condition, it will stop itself. But it cant find the function because it hasn't been declared yet. How do I do this?

Comment: never mind, I solved it

Comment: Please can you post the answer yourself instead of just saying 'I solved it'.

Comment: Do you have an onLoad handler around this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var loop=null;
function startBallEasy() {
    if(foo==1) {
        alert("foo is 1!");
    } else {
        clearTimeout(loop);
    }

    loop = setTimeout("startBallEasy()",10);
}
setTimeout("startBallEasy()",10);
```

You can use `setInterval`(if you don't want to use recursion function) in place of `setTimeout` like,

```
var foo = 1;
var loop=null;
function startBallEasy() {
    if(foo==1) {
        alert("foo is 1!");
    } else {
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
}
loop = setInterval("startBallEasy()",10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions and variable declarations are hoisted in JavaScript; you have access to `stopLoop`. It should work as-is. So…

> Before you tell me that javascript reads code from top to bottom, let me just say that I know that.

It doesn’t in that way!

Also, passing strings to `setTimeout` is a bad idea; it’s like `eval`. Just pass a function. In this case, you can even make it shorter and cleaner at the same time!

```
loop = setTimeout(startBallEasy, 10);
```

Comment: It's kind of stupid how the only correct answer has the lowest score.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little lack of the logic in your code. You check `foo` and then do something depending on the value, and then you start a new timeout again, nevertheless what `foo` is.

To fix this, you need to move the timeout into the `if`:

```
function startBallEasy() {
    if(foo==1) {
        alert("foo is 1!");
        loop = setTimeout("startBallEasy()",10);
    } else {
        stopLoop();
    }    
}
```

Comment: i cant, because i forgot to mention, in my actual program, I have more methods after the `if...else`

Answer (score 0):

The string or function you pass to `setTimeout` will be executed in a global context.

If the code you have posted here is wrapped in an `onLoad` handler or similar, this would mean that `startBallEasy` is local to that handler, and is therefore inaccessible in the global scope. If the code you have posted is all there is, then it should work fine, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw38V/) (warning: your code has no exit condition, so what you will see is an endless stream of "foo is 1!" alerts).

The solution, as minitech has mentioned, is to pass a function that closes over its dependency (`startBallEasy`) to `setTimeout`.

```
var foo = 1;
var loop;

function startBallEasy() {
    if(foo==1) {
        alert("foo is 1!");
    } else {
        stopLoop();
    }

    loop = setTimeout(function(){startBallEasy();},10);
}

function stopLoop() {
    clearTimeout(loop);
}
```

Do note that there is currently no exit condition to your code. Here is a slightly modified demonstration that counts from 0 to 9, logging the state of `foo` on each iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/JWyzy/